# Get the value automatically of a list in terraform Azure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

any help for this situation please :

***My parent module :***

**main.tf**

```
#-------------------------------
#    HP
#-------------------------------
# The hostpool uses logic from var.pool_type to set the majority of the fields. 
# Description and RDP properties are "changed" every deployment. Lifecycle block prevents this update. 
resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool" "pool" {
  resource_group_name              = var.resource_group_name
  location                         = var.location
  name                             = var.hp_name
  friendly_name                    = var.hp_friendly_name
  validate_environment             = var.validate_environment
  custom_rdp_properties            = var.custom_rdp_properties
  description                      = "The ${var.hp_name}-HP was created with Terraform on ${formatdate("EEEE, DD-MMM-YY", timestamp())}."
  type                             = var.hp_type
  maximum_sessions_allowed         = var.maximum_sessions_allowed
  personal_desktop_assignment_type = var.desktop_assignment_type
  start_vm_on_connect              = var.start_vm_on_connect
  load_balancer_type               = var.load_balancer_type
  preferred_app_group_type         = var.preferred_app_group_type
  scheduled_agent_updates {
    enabled  = var.enable_agent_update_schedule
    timezone = var.timezone
    schedule {
      day_of_week = var.schedule01_day_of_week 
      hour_of_day = var.schedule01_hour_of_day
    }
    schedule {
      day_of_week = var.schedule02_day_of_week
      hour_of_day = var.schedule02_hour_of_day
    }
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      description,
      custom_rdp_properties,
      maximum_sessions_allowed
    ]
  }
  tags = var.tags
}
# The hostpools registration token. Used by the DSC extension/AVD agent to tie the virtual machine to the hostpool as a "Sessionhost."
resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool_registration_info" "token" {
  hostpool_id     = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.pool.id
  expiration_date = timeadd(timestamp(), "2h")
   lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
            expiration_date
    ]
  }
}
```

**Outputs.tf**

```
output "pool" {
  description = "The pool created by this module"
  value       = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.pool
}

output "token" {
  description = "The hostpool token created for this pool."
  value       = local.token
  sensitive   = true
}
```

**Called module :**

main.tf

```
module "host_pool" {
  # Required Input
  source    = "../../infra-modules/modules/azure_virtual_desktop_v3/avd_00_host_pool"
  providers = {
    azurerm = azurerm.reg
   } 
  for_each = var.host_pool #{ for sh in var.host_pool : sh.hp_name => sh }
   #Required
  resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_name 
  location                     = var.location
  hp_name                      = each.value["hp_name"]         
  hp_type                      = each.value["hp_type"]         
  load_balancer_type           = each.value["load_balancer_type"]         #var.load_balancer_type  

 #Optionnal
  hp_friendly_name             = try(each.value["hp_friendly_name"], null)         
  start_vm_on_connect          = try(each.value["start_vm_on_connect"], null)        
  custom_rdp_properties        = try(each.value["custom_rdp_properties"], null)         
  maximum_sessions_allowed     = try(each.value["maximum_sessions_allowed"], null)         
  desktop_assignment_type      = try(each.value["desktop_assignment_type"], null)         
  timezone                     = try(each.value["timezone"], null)         #var.timezone
  schedule01_day_of_week       = try(each.value["schedule01_day_of_week"], null)         
  schedule01_hour_of_day       = try(each.value["schedule01_hour_of_day"], null)         
#         
  schedule02_day_of_week       = try(each.value["schedule02_day_of_week"], null)         
  schedule02_hour_of_day       = try(each.value["schedule02_hour_of_day"], null)         
  tags                         = try(each.value["tags"], null)         

}
```

***variables.tf :***

```
variable "host_pool" {
   default     = {}

}
```

***terraform.tfvars  :***

```
  host_pool = {

  host_pool_security = { }
  host_pool_administration = { }
  host_pool_finances = { }

}
```

When i need to use host pool id with the application group, how to call automatically all the values between [] for the list in the tfvars.

For example i can get the first when i put the value :  `module.host_pool["host_pool_security"].pool.id`

Any solution to get the value automatically between the [""] please ?

Comment: Something like `values(module.host_pool)[*].pool.id`?

Comment: It not working with [*] 
host_pool = {

  host_pool_security = { }
  host_pool_administration = { }
  host_pool_finances = { }

}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where do you want to have those values.

Answer (score 0):

Check ,if you can do something like below for your scenario where parameters can be called dynamically:

Example:

Declared desired list variable which has parameters like for examaple: name, access_type.

**Variables.tf**

```
variable "containers_list" {
  type = list
  default = [
{ name = "some1", access_type = "private" },
 {name = "some2", access_type = "private"}
]
 }

 variable "Storage_list" {
  type = list
  default = ["storge1", "storage2”
 }

locals {
    flat_list = setproduct(var.Storage_list, var.containers_list)
}
```

Then each of those parameters can be retrieved using count and its index.

**name   = each.value[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8DSO.png).name
*and*   container_access_type = each.value[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8DSO.png).access_type**

**Main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mystorage_account" {
  for_each = toset(var.Storage_list) 
  name=each.value
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier = " "
  account_replication_type = " "
}


resource "azurerm_storage_container" "newcontainer" {
  
  for_each              = {for idx, val in local.flat_list: idx => val}
  name                  = each.value[1].name
  container_access_type = each.value[1].access_type
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.mystorage_account[each.value[0]].name
}
```

**This way the name and accesstype values in my example here in variable files are fetched dynamically- upon terraform apply.**

[image]